# ScrollHeight not changing when ng-repeat is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've provided a Plunker below, when you click the button a loop is performed that adds data to an ng-repeat. After each loop the data is supposed to console.log() the ScrollHeight of the container. I would assume that it would log three unique number, but instead it logs the final height of the div three times. Any thoughts?

http://plnkr.co/edit/dMbrWsrwfQuf0HCv8Ggn?p=preview

CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.shares = [{
  name: 'all'
}, {
  name: 'day'
}, {
  name: 'I'
}, {
  name: 'dream'
}, {
  name: 'about'
}, {
  name: 'javascript'
}, ]

$scope.heights = [];
$scope.dataset = [];

var tableview = document.getElementById('tableview');

var TableViewOne = new TableView($scope.shares);


$scope.testing = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    TableViewOne.setData();
    TableViewOne.setHeight();
  }

}

function TableView(data) {

  var heights = [];

  this.setData = function() {
    var temp = data;
    for (var i = 0, len = temp.length; i < len; i++) {
      $scope.dataset.push(temp[i]);
    }
  }

  this.setHeight = function() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      heights.push(tableview.scrollHeight);
      console.log(heights);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give width, height and overflow CSS to "ul" tag in style.css

Style.css:

```
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:overlay;
```

Updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/2dyER88Hkx1RNGGZ5iSG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

When you update the model, angular **does not update its view immediately** inside the same function. Angular updates the view at the end of the current cycle within its digest loop. That's why you don't see the updated height immediately.

When working with MVC architecture like angular, you **should not access** the view (DOM) directly in your controller's code. Try to restructure your code to only modify the model and let angular handle the DOM manipulation for you.

If you need to handle scroll event to add more items, you could try this:

```
$("#tableview").scroll(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){ //let angular aware of changes from events outside of angular.

       //do your logic to add more items.
    });
});
```

Another way to wrap this logic to make it integrated nicely with angular is to write a custom directive.

Comment: Is there a way I can see the height immediately? I'm assuming this involved the digest cycle.

Comment: @rjm226: a workaround for this is using $timeout to schedule the task for the next cycle (when the DOM was updated in the previous cycle), but it's not recommended.

Comment: Theoretically how would you achieve what I'm trying to achieve. I'm just trying to figure out the scrollheight of a container everytime I add data to the container and append it to an array.

Comment: @rjm226: what do you use the `scrollheight` for? Why do you need to figure out the scrollHeight `right after` you add an element to the array?

Comment: @rjm226: what do you mean by infinite scroll? Displaying a scroll is achievable via CSS.

Comment: I've got a list of 10,000 items. I show 10 at a time. When the users scrolls the entire height of the div I will add 10 more items and remove 10 from the front.

Comment: @rjm226: I think you can handle the scroll event outside angular (with jQuery for example) and call into angular by accessing the scope of current element. See my edit for some pseudo-code.